# can alpha particles cause perturbation

Tags: particle-physics

Can alpha particles coming from a matter cause the molecules surrounding that matter to move (cause perturbation)? in these cases:
Air, Water, Oil, Grease
Thank you

Comment: When you Google the momentum of an $ \alpha $ particle, compared to the mass of an $O_2$ molecule, what does that tell you?

Comment: I googled it and i couldn't find a clear answer to my question

Answer (score 1):

You have to realize the enormous number of particles in matter, Avogadro's number , about $10^{23}$ molecules per mole,  to be compared with 1 alpha particle interacting through them . It will leave a path due to ionizing the atoms and molecules in its way , the path will have a width less than a micron.

This is more striking in [a cloud chamber](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/particles/cloud.html), and it was one of the first clear indications of how radiation interacts with matter.

[image: cloud alpha]

In emulsions , which are solid, the ionization paths are shorter:

[image: alpha in emulsion]

> [A photographic emulsion](http://www.sciencephoto.com/subject/Physics/particle%20physics/particle%20pictures%20-%20emulsion%20pictures) impregnated with a radio- active thorium salt reveals the tracks of alpha particles when developed. As Ernest Rutherford & Frederick Soddy found in 1900-1902, the decay of thorium initiates a chain of decays. First one radioactive element is formed, then that decays to another, & so on. This is why the emulsion picture shows the tracks of two or more alpha particles emerging from the same spot: they are the result of successive stages in the decay of a single nucleus. (The length of the alpha tracks in this negative picture is about 0.03 mm).

The path length depends on the density of the medium which  absorbs the kinetic energy of the alphas.

[This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_particle) describes the interactions of alpha particles with matter.

Answer (score 0):

Alpha particles are absorbed by 10 cm of air and they are the least penetrating of the three types of radioactive decay. Thinking about it, my comment above might have been badly worded, my apologies if it was not as helpful as I intended.

When the alpha particles emerge from the nucleus, they are lighter in mass than air molecules but they are moving relatively quickly. They can lose energy in two ways, either by ionising the air molecules,  which is the most likely method, although the $O_2$ molecule will still move in accordance with the laws of conservation of momentum and energy.

They may have a very  small chance of getting through the screen of 8 electrons surrounding  the oxygen (or 7 in the case of nitrogen)  atom and imparting their momentum  directly to the oxygen nucleus, but I would guess this would be  a very rare event compared to the ionisation process.

Once the alpha particle has lost its momentum, its chance of causing perturbation of a air molecule is pretty much nil.

Here's a picture of the three types of radiation and how much material is needed to stop each of them.

[image]

Image source: [Cyberphysics](http://www.cyberphysics.co.uk/topics/radioact/Radio/ion&penet.htm)

Comment: thanks alot man, great illustration and quite a good answer, I understood it perfectly!!